# How to use RSpec expectations in irb

Tags: ruby, rspec, irb, rspec-expectations

I'd want to use `[1,2,3].should include(1)` in irb. I tried:

```
~$ irb
1.9.3p362 :001 > require 'rspec/expectations'
 => true 
1.9.3p362 :002 > include RSpec::Matchers
 => Object 
1.9.3p362 :003 > [1,2,3].should include(1)
TypeError: wrong argument type Fixnum (expected Module)
    from (irb):3:in `include'
    from (irb):3
    from /home/andrey/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

But it doesn't work though [it's a valid case](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations#collection-membership). How can I use `[1,2,3].should include(1)`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are close, but calling `include` on top-level you will be calling `Module#include`. To get around it you need to remove the original include method so that RSpec's `include` gets called instead.

First let's figure out where the system `include` comes from:

```
> method :include
=> #<Method: main.include>
```

Ok. It looks like it's defined in `main`. This is the Ruby top-level object. So let's rename and remove the original include:

```
> class << self; alias_method :inc, :include; remove_method :include; end
```

Now we can get down to business:

```
> require 'rspec'
> inc RSpec::Matchers
> [1,2,3].should include(1)
=> true
```