# is a one-line test like this possible in rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'd like to do something like the following:

```
require 'rspec-expectations'
"bat".length.should eq(3)
# => NoMethodError: undefined method `eq' for main:Object
```

Is something like this possible? How would I need to change it? Would I need to require `'rspec-expectations'`?

Comment: what your goal is? maybe simple ruby technique can help you.

Comment: I'm trying to do a quick demo of how rspec works and would like to be able to do it in irb. I know I can create a simple file but more for demo purposes

Comment: @Priti but that has nothing to do with Rspec

Comment: @Priti please don't delete comments that already have been answered, it makes the conversation hard to follow for others.

Comment: @padde you also delete the comment,I deleted as that comment has no point. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In irb:

```
require 'rspec-expectations'
include RSpec::Matchers

"bat".length.should eq(3)
```

Comment: thx, this looks great. When it's not met, it's a little ugly but gets job done.

Comment: as a heads-up, you might run into issues with the above technique such as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14749047/how-to-use-rspec-expectations-in-irb?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

Try [`interactive_rspec`](https://github.com/amatsuda/interactive_rspec):

```
gem install interactive_rspec
```

then

```
irspec
001> "bat".length.should eq(3)
.

Finished in 0.00006 seconds
1 example, 0 failures
=> true
```