# How can I use rspec expectations and matchers outside of Rspec?

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec-expectations

I have a script which has evolved into needing to do some assertions and matching.

It is written in ruby, and I have included `rspec` in the Gemfile and required it.

I found this very helpful SO post on how to use in `irb`:

[How to use RSpec expectations in irb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14749047/how-to-use-rspec-expectations-in-irb)

I also found the following:

[Use RSpec's "expect" etc. outside a describe ... it block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23624655/use-rspecs-expect-etc-outside-a-describe-it-block)

```
class BF
   include ::Rspec::Matchers

   def self.test
     expect(1).to eq(1)
   end
end

BF.test
```

I get an error at the `expect` line.

Comment: ... What error do you get?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you `include` a module, it makes its methods available to *instances* of the class.  Your `test` method is a singleton method (a "class method"), not an instance method, and thus will never have access to methods provided by mixed-in modules.  To fix it, you can do:

```
class BF
   include ::RSpec::Matchers

   def test
     expect(1).to eq(1)
   end
end

BF.new.test
```

If you want the `RSpec::Matchers` methods to be available to singleton methods of `BF`, you can instead `extend` the module:

```
class BF
   extend ::RSpec::Matchers

   def self.test
     expect(1).to eq(1)
   end
end

BF.test
```

Comment: ah, it is the extend that looks like what I want it to do!  Tryuing now!